# An Error occurred during authorization, please try again later: Python Social Auth LinkedIn

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, python-social-auth

My user is getting the following error when the user clicks the Linkedin button on my website and is redirected to LinkedIn user selection page where he should select his account and enter credentials:

```
An Error occurred during authorization, please try again later.
```

How do I fix this error?
I am  using OAuth2 in Social Auth settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django Settings change:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_KEY = 'value'
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_SECRET = 'value'
```

to

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_KEY = 'value'
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_SECRET = 'value'
```